# how to identify the request comming from my interface in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using Nodejs,expressjs,and mongoose to develop a application.Now what is procedure or way to identify that the request hit of my rest api service is from my front end application not from any unknown request.

Answer (score 0):

If your front end application is a browser web page, then there is no real way to limit your REST API service to only your web app.

The issue is that by its very nature the REST API service is available on the web to any client that wants to access it.  You could add some authentication (some sort of secret key) that is required before the REST API service can be accessed, but you cannot hide that secret key in a browser web page.  If the browser web page can get access to the key, then so can anyone else who looks at the code in the web page or on the wire.

Because browsers, by default, will not allow cross origin Ajax calls, you are already protected from some other web pages (on a different site) using your REST API service from the browser.  But, other servers can still use your REST API service.

---

One common way that services attempt to manage the use of their APIs is that they require an API key be obtained for each legitimate use of the API.  If a particular API key is found to be abusing the service, you can revoke the privileges of that API key.  You can grant your own applications API keys (embedded in your web pages ) and you can even change those web keys regular (such as daily) to keep people from copying them once and then using them for a long time.  But a determined hacker will still find a working API key and use it for awhile.

One common way that services attempt to prevent excess usage of their API and protect the integrity of their service is to implement rate limiting.  You establish what you think is a reasonable number of API calls per second (or some such metric) that your own app would not exceed and you measure the number of API calls coming from each endpoint and if they exceed some threshold, then you either delay or deny or error their calls until they stop exceeding your threshold.